# Thick underline behind text

Tags: html, css, underline

How to reproduce this sort of underline behind the text ABC using spans and css?

[image: thick underline behinde image]

I have been able to do underline *below* the text with nested `span` and colored `border-bottom`, but cannot get it *behind* the image and *above* the text base line.

```html
<p style='font-size:100px'>
  <span style='border-bottom:30px magenta solid'><span>A</span></span>
  <span style='border-bottom:60px magenta solid'><span>B</span></span>
  <span style='border-bottom:90px magenta solid'><span>C</span></span>
</p>
```

Comment: How about using `z-index`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another possibility:

```css
p {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: arial;
}

span {
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -0.4em 0 0 magenta;
}

span:nth-child(2) {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -0.55em 0 0 magenta;
}

span:nth-child(3) {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -0.7em 0 0 magenta;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>A</span><span>B</span><span>C</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 10):

Someone asked me about this design style today so I thought I'd look at options in 2020. Here is an example of the output with this technique (see snippet below):

[image]

The technique uses a background gradient on a nested span:

```css
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: black;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h1.gradient span {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,0,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,0,255,0) 16%, rgba(255,0,255,1) 16%, rgba(255,0,255,1) 41%, rgba(255,0,255,0) 41%);
}

h1.padding span {
  padding: 0 0.5em 0 0.1em;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="gradient padding"><span>This text has an 'underline' behind the text. It can wrap and it can have padding.</span></h1>
```

This allows the h1 to remain block level but applies the style to the inline element beneath it which allows the style to apply to the text and wrap on multiple lines. The 'underline' can be positioned by changing the linear-gradient stops.

If some horizontal padding is needed to make the underline stick out from the text on the left or right side more you can also use padding with `box-decoration-break` which will keep the padding across each wrapped line. `box-decoration-break` works on all modern browsers, see [caniuse for details](https://caniuse.com/#search=box-decoration-break).

Answer (score 5):

http://codepen.io/OxyDesign/pen/eHAac

With :before in absolute position

CSS

```
.underlined-text {
  font-size:100px;
}
.underlined {
  display: block;
  float:left;
  height:92px;
  position:relative;
}
.underlined:before {
  display: block;
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  background:#f66;
  z-index:-1;
}
.underlined.first:before {
  height:15px;
}
.underlined.second:before {
  height:30px;
}
.underlined.third:before {
  height:45px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

We can use background and play with `background-position-y`

```css
span {
  font: 36px sans-serif;
  /*                                         ↓ y position */
  background: linear-gradient(pink, pink) 0 90% / 100% 8px no-repeat;
  /*                                                    ↑ line height */
}
```

```html
<span>Lorem ipsum</span>
```

More flexible version by using variables:

```css
span {
  font: 36px sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(pink, pink) 0 var(--y-pos, 90%) / 100% var(--size, 8px) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<span>Lorem ipsum</span><br>
<span style="--y-pos: 70%;--size: 10px;">Lorem ipsum</span><br>
<span style="--y-pos: 50%;--size: 15px;">Lorem ipsum</span><br>
<span style="--y-pos: 100%;--size: 5px;">Lorem ipsum</span>
```

Comment: Again, this is a really nice solution. How would you control the right and left sides of the red bar to make it pixel perfect flush inline with the text?

Comment: perfect answer, this should be the top one

Answer (score 3):

Try using `background-position`:

HTML:

```
<p style='font-size:100px'><span class="a">A</span><span class="b">B</span><span class="c">C</span>
```

**CSS**:

```
p>span {
    background-image: url(http://i234.photobucket.com/albums/ee79/xxjetaimmexx/pink.jpg);
    background-position: bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.a {
    background-size:100% 33%
}
.b {
    background-size:100% 50%
}
.c {
    background-size:100% 70%
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/355/

Key is to alter the background-size of each span.

Answer (score 2):

you can indeed use a gradient, the gradient can be animated and be drawn through a few lines inside an inline element.

```css
p {
  font-size: 100px;
}

p span {
  background: linear-gradient(red, red)left bottom repeat-x;
  background-size: 35px 35px;
  transition:0.5s;
}

p span:nth-child(2) {
  background-size: 50px 50px;
}

p span:nth-child(3) {
  background-size: 65px 65px
}
p:hover span {
background-size: 0 0px;
```

```html
<p><span>A</span><span>B</span><span>C</span></p>

<p><span>Aaa aaaaa aaaa aa aaaaaa aaaaaA</span><span>Bbbbb bbbb bbb  bb bbbbb bbb bbbb B</span><span>Cccccc cc ccc cccccccc cc ccccc  C</span></p>
```

Comment: Really nice solution. How would you control the right and left sides of the red bar if you needed to, like bring it in 10px either side, or extend it 20px each side?

Comment: @AgentZebra it is drawn inside the span containing the letter, so i do not understand where you want to add or remove 10px from taht space? remove 10px, where does go the letter? on top the next or previous one? away from the previous or next one? inline element may take text-indent or horizontal padding if background-size is not what you need. I actually do not understand your question:), my english maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Use `text-decoration` + `text-decoration-skip-ink: none;` + negative `text-underline-offset`:

```css
p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 48px;
  text-decoration:red underline 20px;
  text-underline-offset: -10px;
  text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
}

p span {
  text-decoration:green underline 30px;
  text-underline-offset: -20px;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem <span>ipsum</span> dolor sit amet,<br> consectetur <span>adipisicing</span> elit.<br> Quidem, repellendus.
```

Comment: This is the best one!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another trick

Play around with the line height and border values.

```css
span{
  font-family: "arial", san-serif;
  font-size:32px;
  
  display:inline-block;
  border-bottom: 12px solid #50D3CB;
  line-height: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<span>text to be underlined</span>
```