# How to make border-bottom overlap text in CSS?

Tags: html, css, border, padding, underline

I'm trying to make my underline on a word thick and overlapping the word above it, sort of like a negative padded underline. Like how the word "maygha" is underlined in this image.

[image]

This is what I have right now:

```css
span {
  border-bottom: 16px solid #a2c1f5;
}
```

```html
<h1> hi there! <br> i'm <span> maygha!</span></h1>
```

Comment: Use a negative ```margin-bottom``` so that the "hitbox" of the span is higher. Now your ```border-bottom``` has the ability to touch the text.

Answer (score 3):

Simply, use `::after` like this

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

h1 span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

h1 span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: 0;
  height: .5rem;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h1> hi there! <br> i'm <span> maygha!</span></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks! How could I change the position of the background (move it higher/ lower)?

Comment: You can use bottom, top and transforms ...
now , you can see I change bottom 20%

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use `background-position-y`. Thanks to [@doğukan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67694940/6904888) for the excellent answer.

```css
span {
  background: linear-gradient(#cfddff, #cfddff) 0 70% / 100% 10px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h1> hi there, <br> i'm <span> maygha!</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would combine `inline-block` for the `span` with adjusting its height in relation to the font size using `em`s

```css
span {
    border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 255, .5);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0.7em;
}
```

```html
<h1>
My <span>text</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is through `box-shadow` as you can see in the following snippet. The downside is you need to give an alpha component to the color of the shadow.

```css
span {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)
}
```

```html
<h1> hi there! <br> i'm <span> maygha!</span></h1>
```