CSS Custom Highlight API with underlined text on Safari
I'm working on a project where users can highlight content by selecting text and choosing a highlight style. I'm using the CSS Custom Highlight API, which is relatively new in terms of browser support. For my purposes, I only need to support recent versions of Safari and Chrome.
In the highlight API, highlights are created in JavaScript based on a range, then registered in CSS. They can then be styled using the ::highlight() pseudo-element. This is much easier than other methods of drawing highlights in HTML (such as hard-coding spans, programmatically traversing text nodes and inserting spans, or drawing absolutely-positioned rectangles behind the text) – especially when the highlight needs to continue through formatting tags and other elements.
When styling a highlight, the available set of CSS properties is limited. One option is underlining text with text-decoration and its related properties. This works great in Chrome, but I'm unable to get text-underline-offset and text-decoration-thickness to work with highlights in Safari. This makes the underline hard to see. Those properties work great when directly styling a span, but not when styling a highlight.


const span1 = document.getElementById('span-1');
range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(span1);

let h = new Highlight(range);
CSS.highlights.set('my-highlight', h);
body {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}

::highlight(my-highlight) {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: yellowgreen;
  text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
  text-underline-offset: 0.1em;
  text-decoration-thickness: 0.2em;
}

#span-2 {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: yellowgreen;
  text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
  text-underline-offset: 0.1em;
  text-decoration-thickness: 0.2em;
}
<p>This is a <b>paragraph</b> with many <i>text nodes,</i> <span id="span-1">which is <b>easy</b> to highlight in an <i>underline</i> style</span> thanks to the Highlight API.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph with <span id="span-2">directly underlined</span> text to compare.</p>



Chrome version 129 (what I want):

Safari version 18.0 (broken):

I'm assuming this is either a bug in Safari, or a feature that's not fully implemented yet.
Is there a workaround that would allow me to get the style I want in Safari, within the bounds of the Custom Highlight API? Maybe some way to simulate an underline with a well-tuned text shadow or background color?

A linear gradient as background, maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61361501/1427878

@mplungjan, nice tip – thank you! Done.

@C3roe, background-color is a supported property on ::highlight() pseud-elements, but unfortunately background is not.

Can you use -webkit-text-decoration-thickness: 2px; or have a fallback for Safari?

I tried -webkit-text-decoration-thickness: 2px; – unfortunately, that doesn't work either.

The spec uses CSS Text Decoration Module Level 3, whereas thickness is defined in Level 4. Might need updates in the spec also.
